# AJAX and PHP communication : the safe way

Tags: php, jquery

As already discussed in one of my previous topics, I'm trying to send JSON to and get it from a php script. Currently, everything is working well. I've organized my php script so it gets the parameter in the url and based on that (with the help of switch statement) I call the appropriate functions.
However, what I've noted is that by looking at the source, one can easily copy the link to the php script and manipulate data through it. That's something I'm not comfortable with. 
What are the alternatives?

Sample of .html ajax call:

```
function getAllData(){
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "dataDao.php?f=getAll",
    datatype: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function(data){ 
        $.each(JSON.parse(data), function(index, value) {
          alert(value['firstName'] );
        });
    },
    error: function(err){
      alert('error!' + JSON.stringify(err));
    }
 });

}
```

Sample of php code

```
switch($_GET['f']) {
case 'getAll':
    $result = getAll();
    break;
case 'getOne':
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $result = getOne($id);
    break;
case 'addTo':
    $result = addToArray();
default:
}
```

Comment: One alternative is to `define` URLS and use constants throughout.

Comment: You want to hear about [authorization](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html).

Comment: I'm curious what you worst case scenario is. (Also shouldn't you be using $_POST in your PHP code)? No one examining the HTML source actually knows the structure of your php code that's receiving your POST. Of course, you'll want to do sanity checking on anything that gets passed.

Comment: instead of sending f=GetAll in the URL, why not send it through POST using the "data" attribute of jquery AJAX. like @DevlshOne said you can define it in a var before you send it too

Comment: @A.O. that would be the same - you can inspect any request headers / body, then reproduce it.

Comment: @A.O. — Because that does precisely nothing for security.

Comment: @J.Robertson the PHP code may not be forward facing but the Javascript is. WITHOUT SECURITY, simply having the URLs for the AJAX routines allows curious users to directly access them and play havoc with the results.

Comment: Trying to procure secure communication channels is like trying to build an unsinkable ship out of paper, and mud... you'll just have to focus on not not being vulnerable to the common forms of attack

Comment: 'play havoc with the results' - how so?

Sure, users may be able to pass whatever they want to your PHP script (attempting SQL Injection, etc). But I am curious what they are going to pass that worries you so. You should be sanity checking everything that comes in anyway so you tightly control what gets echo'd by your php code.

Comment: Well I can do a lot about security, that's no doubt another issue, but it can be managed. However, since I return the result set in this manner `echo json_encode($result);`, one can get the raw data view through the url.

Comment: yeah, but your php script only returns that data if it gets a very specific string. How is the user going to know the proper string to pass to get that data?

Comment: By simply examining the source code. Still, I know, user won't be able to get to the data he or she couldn't get through the HTML, that's true. I suppose I could add a verification token, then it wouldn't be _that_ easy to access the raw data (but it would be possible, I know, by simulating a POST request).

Comment: @DevlshOne constants are outdated, better use objects and DI pattern

Comment: @J.Robertson You sound like an expert! Please show us some examples of how you've 'sanity checked everything'! I'm sure some of us less experienced users would love to see it and it would certainly apply to the original poster's question.

Comment: How is a person going to examine your php script code from the front end? You're losing me there. 

@DevlshOne - no need to be snide. Not once did I claim to be an expert. I'm merely asking what I think are reasonable questions. I am, as I'm sure you and other are, curious about questions of security. If there's a method to view the source of a php script called via AJAX, I would very much like to know that.

Comment: I never claimed nor did I say that there's a way of examining the source of the PHP. Not at all! Merely the raw data, returned by the function. Therefore, if you examine the ajax call in the original post, you see the name of the php file and how the function is called. You can then copy that into the url and get the raw json, returned by the script. I felt as though that was not right, but obviously, that's fine. As long as code is sound.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There aren't any alternatives. Your public facing interface is your HTTP server, not your JavaScript. You must implement whatever input sanity checking, data escaping, authentication and authorization you need at the server level.